# lhs2tex include file extension

Tags: lhs2tex

We are using lhs2TeX in a big project. Thus we have many (executable) documents. We have a common .sty file and we also have a common file in which we keep all the often used lhs2TeX directives e.g.

```
%format alpha = "\alpha"
```

I have given this file the suffix of .l2t but is there a common / better suffix?

Answer (score 1):

There's no required suffix, but lhs2TeX itself uses `.fmt` as a suffix for this sort of file.